# Linked question does not show up on sidebar

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

[This question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/what-topics-do-academians-tend-to-be-attracted) contains a link to [this question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/should-you-post-irrelevant-post-in-fan-page); a such, each question should have a link in the sidebar to the other. For some reason, though, this is not the case.

Is this a bug? I'm inclined the guess that it has something to do with the fact that the first question was migrated to Community Building from Academia, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've noticed this on a question on Physics, too.